# Ubuntu Server installed on high capactiy Micro-sized USB

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, partitioning, flash

Just out of curiosity, I would like to ask if anyone has experience installing Ubuntu 16.04 lts server on micro-sized USB flash drives with capacity of 128GB that come preformated in exfat as per the link [here](https://patriotmemory.com/product/tab-usb-3-0-flash-drives/).

I have installs running perfectly on 32gb USBs, basically within the limit of the fat filesystem, but wish to know if an install of Ubuntu could happen on these micro-sized 128gb flash drives.

**Update**

Great experiment succeeded as expected with a 32GB of SWAP and 92GB for /. This will leave the 2 hdd ports of the Dell PowerEdge 1950 Gen II (max 2TB @ raid 1) totally available for data. Besides, it is so small that I can still attach the front bezel of the server with no issues at all. Apart from a slower install process, I have no operational latency.

[image]

Comment: @Melebius, no the micro USB is factory preformatted in exFAT and would not know if there will be issues to install Ubuntu on such disks.

Comment: I think it is irrelevant as normal Linux installation would reformat them, mostly using ext* (ext3 or ext4).

Comment: Yes I agree, what I doubt if the installer would initially recognize the card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preformatted file system type does not matter as Linux will re-format the destination partition during installation if it’s not suitable.

The part of the linked web page containing the important information is the following:

> The Patriot Tab **is compatible with** Windows® 8, Windows® 7, Windows® Vista®, Windows® XP, Windows® 2000, Windows® ME, **Linux 2.4 and later**, Mac® OS9, X and later.

So if you are not going to install a prehistoric Linux version (there is Linux 4.x as of now), there should be no problem.

Comment: Just ordered it, will try it out and let you know

Comment: the size is so appropriate as it allows me to use the front usb port and still close the front bezel, see image. Install with guided LVM partitioning was slow, and will try to reinstall using manual partitioning. Operation speed was normal - compared to an HDD. Dell BIOS recognises such as emulates it as an HDD.